# mutt: show email list with collapsed threads by defalt

Tags: mutt

There is `collapse-all` function in mutt. I bound it to `_` symbol in `.muttrc`:

```
bind index _ collapse-all
```

Is it possible to run it by default when opening the emails list, so all the unread threads were collapsed when I open mutt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write in `.muttrc`:

```
exec collapse-all
```